# How to add a line in multiple files in unix

Tags: python-2.7, shell

I want to add a common plain text line to all the files present in same Unix directory.And i want to add this above a specific keyword present in all the files  and save it using <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

i did try the below script but i am able to add only one line or one word above a specific keyword, i need to add multiple lines above this

```
for i in *; 
do sed -i 's/KEYWORD/datatoinsert\nKEYWORD/' "$i";
done
```

Any help is appreciated, even if someone has tried this in Python i would like to try that as well.

Comment: Please show examples. I inserted several lines using your method and it worked.

Comment: `for i in *; 
do sed -i 's/KEYWORD/datat1\ndata2\data3\nKEYWORD/' "$i";
done`

Comment: figured out that running the above code adds multiple lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no loop needed, you can add the 'plain text' line with a simple `sed` edit in place, e.g.

```
$ sed -i '/keyword/s/^/plain text\n/' *
```

**Example Files**

```
$ cat file1.txt
word
keyword
rest
```

**Example Use/Changes**

```
$ sed -i '/keyword/s/^/plain text\n/' *
$ cat file1.txt
word
plain text
keyword
rest
```

Where you can break down the `sed` command as

- `sed -i` edit the files in place
- `/keyword/` locate line containing `keyword`
- `s` substitute command, e.g `s/find/replace/`
- `^` match the beginnng of line
- `plain text\n` the replace text

So you essentially find the beginning of the line containing `keyword` and replace (insert) the text `plain text\n` containing its own newline there.

Comment: My code replaces the Keyword and then add the text to be inserted then again adds the KEYWORD
Is there a way that it doesn't remove the KEYWORD and only increments the position of the row to the next line 
and enter the new text in place of it

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I do above. except I never replace `keyword`, I simply find the **beginning of the line** that contains `keyword` with `/keyword/` before the `'s/find/replace/'`, and then insert '`plaint text\n`' as a new line at the **beginning of the line**. This works no matter where `keyword` appears in the line. (e.g.. it would work for the line `"keyword"` or the line `"some keyword here"`)

Answer (score 0):

With bash and sed, adding the contents of `replacement` before the keyword `dog`:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
replacement="cats\neverywhere"
sed  "s/dog/$replacement\ndog/g" "$1"
```

Examples:

```
$ cat f1
one
two
dog
three

$ ./test.sh f1
one
two
cats
everywhere
dog
three

$ cat f2
dog
so close
no matter
dog
far
dog

$ ./test.sh f2
cats
everywhere
dog
so close
no matter
cats
everywhere
dog
far
cats
everywhere
dog
```

Comment: My code replaces the Keyword and then add the text to be inserted then again adds the KEYWORD
Is there a way that it doesn't remove the KEYWORD and only increments the position of the row to the next line 
and enter the new text in place of it

Comment: I am not sure if that's how sed operates, but why is the procedure important since the end result is the desired one? Does sed not meet your performance requirements?

Comment: at the end of the edit i have to store the exact config that was added in other file and log the report, removing the KEYWORD and adding that again adds this also in the logs which i do not want

Comment: @rahul  _adding that again adds this also in the logs which i do not want_ : this sentence makes no sense to me, and it is not something you stated in the original post. 
Please state **clearly** the **full** desired result in the original post (you can edit it).
 Maybe add some examples as well.